# UNIR CONSULTA SQL CON PRODECIMIENTO ALMACENADO

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hola buen día a todos.

Tengo una duda y quisiera que me ayudaran y aprender.

Se trata de SQL o de Vb.net

Tengo una tabla Ítem, de la que recopilo datos como el código, la descripción, el precio, etc.

Queda algo así:

| Id | Código | Descripción | Precio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100100 | Ítem de prueba | 200.00 |
| 2 | 100200 | Ítem de prueba2 | 800.00 |

Y tengo un procedimiento almacenado al que se le envía el parámetro id(que es el id de el artículo de la tabla Ítem) y retorna la venta máxima que se ha hecho en un mes de ese artículo, así como la venta promedio de los últimos 6 meses.

Queda algo así:

| Itemid | Venta Máxima | Venta Promedio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1200 |

Dado que ambas consultas tiene en común el ID del producto, hay alguna manera de unir ambos resultados en una sola fila, por ejemplo

| Id | Código | Descripción | Precio | itemid | Venta Máxima | Venta Promedio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100100 | Ítem de Prueba | 200.00 | 1 | 1234 | 1200 |
| 2 | 100200 | Ítem de Prueba 2 | 800.00 | 2 | 3456 | 300 |

Actualmente lo que hago es que en la aplicación, realizo la consulta de la tabla "Ítem" y la del procedimiento almacenado, ambos los almaceno en un datatable distinto, luego con un "for each" recorro el datatable 1 y le voy agregando los datos del datatable 2, pero toma demasiado tiempo ya que son alrededor de cien mil filas.

¿Qué me sugieren?
Gracias de antemano.
Les adjunto el códig del SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DatosInvCritico] @itemid INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @maxima AS NUMERIC(18, 4),
        @promedio AS NUMERIC(18, 4)
    DECLARE @tabla1 AS TABLE (
        fila INT,
        cantidad NUMERIC(18, 4)
        );

    INSERT INTO @tabla1
    SELECT TOP 7 row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY sum(quantity) DESC
            ) AS rw,
        sum(quantity) AS cantidad
    FROM (
        SELECT quantity,
            FORMAT((
                    SELECT [time]
                    FROM [transaction]
                    WHERE transactionnumber = TransactionEntry.TransactionNumber
                    ), 'yyyy/MM') AS fecha
        FROM transactionentry
        WHERE itemid = @itemid
        ) t1
    GROUP BY fecha

    SELECT @maxima = isnull((
                SELECT TOP 1 cantidad
                FROM @tabla1
                ), 0)

    SELECT @promedio = isnull((
                SELECT ceiling(avg(cantidad))
                FROM @tabla1
                WHERE fila > 1
                    AND fila <= 7
                ), 0)

    SELECT @itemid AS id,
        @maxima AS 'Venta Maxima',
        @promedio AS 'Venta Promedio',
        @promedio * 2 AS 'Compra Sugerida 2 Meses',
        @promedio * 3 AS 'Compra Sugerida 3 Meses'
END
```

Comment: debes colocar el codigo, en modo texto las imagenes no son aceptadas al menos que sea para ilustrar una vista o resultado...

Comment: Haz JOIN con una función que use el procedimiento y regrese `TABLE`. Nota que no es necesario hacer `SELECT` para asignar una variable.